# Конструкция PHP

Tags: php

Есть такой массив шаблонов отправки email:

```
<?
    $mail_templates = array(
    'register' => array(
    'email' => strtolower($options['Login']), 
    'subject' => ...
    )
    );
    ?>
```

И функция:

```
function MailTemplate($name, $options) {
     return $mail_templates[$name];
    }
```

А вызов такой:

```
$options_mail = array('Login' => 'Your Login is');
MailTemplate('register', $options_mail);
```

Хочу чтобы в массив *$mail_template*s подставилось переданное значение **Login** и был возвращен новый массив с набором полей для отправки письма

Comment: так не катит, наверное катит вместо

     $register=>array();

писать

     $register=>function($options) {...}

и соответственно вызывать эту функцию из MailTemplate(), либо применять какой-нибудь шаблонизатор и писать шаблоны в его синтаксисе.

Comment: Думаю так:
function Template($name, $options){
 return $mail_templates = array(
   'register' => array(
        
        'email' => strtolower($options['Login']), 
                      

                       )


   );
 }
}
__________________
function MailTemplate($name, $options) {
   return Template($name, $options)
 }

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос, насколько я понял, такой: как передать в функцию глобальную переменную и наоборот. Вроде как всегда было так(в теле функции):

```
global $mail_templates
```

Comment: Не помогло:
function MailTemplate($name, $options) {
  global $mail_templates;
   return $mail_templates[$name];
 }

Comment: и не поможет, вы вызываете `strtolower($options['Login'])`, в момент  инициализации массива, а не когда запрашиваете значение.

Comment: О_о Вот рабочий код:  
<pre>
<?
$mail_templates['name']='name';

function MailTemplate($name, $options) {
 global $mail_templates; 
 return $mail_templates[$name]; 
 }
 
 
 echo MailTemplate('name', '');
 ?>
</pre>

Comment: @Arc, если вы нашли ошибку в своем ответе, то надо бы её исправить а не оставлять просто комментарий.

Comment: В том-то и дело - ошибки нет. С моим ответом у меня все работает, код я просто так привел, вдруг из него что-нить прояснится.

Comment: ну как это может работать если параметр Login передать нельзя ?

Comment: Я ничего не понял.

Comment: @Arc вы же это предлагаете сделать ? http://ideone.com/AgSYw7